# Why adding add-ons (primeNG) does not work while creating a JHipser project

Tags: jhipster, primeng

When creating a new Jhipster application, I want to install add-ons like primeNG for example. Unfortunately, the application is created well but the add-ons do not install.

I am using version 6.0.1 of JHipster.

I tried to manually install primeNG with the JHipster generator via the 'yo jhipster-primeng' command but this one does not work. I get the following error:

```
events.js:174
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

TypeError: this.getJhipsterAppConfig is not a function
    at module.exports.readConfig (D:\HeliosStudio_1.0.0\nodejs\node_modules\generator-jhipster-primeng\generators\app\index.js:33:47)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\HeliosStudio_1.0.0\nodejs\node_modules\generator-jhipster-primeng\node_modules\generator-jhipster\node_modules\yeoman-generator\lib\index.js:424:27)
    at D:\HeliosStudio_1.0.0\nodejs\node_modules\generator-jhipster-primeng\node_modules\run-async\index.js:25:25
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at D:\HeliosStudio_1.0.0\nodejs\node_modules\generator-jhipster-primeng\node_modules\run-async\index.js:24:19
    at self.env.runLoop.add.completed (D:\HeliosStudio_1.0.0\nodejs\node_modules\generator-jhipster-primeng\node_modules\generator-jhipster\node_modules\yeoman-generator\lib\index.js:425:13)
    at runCallback (timers.js:705:18)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:676:5)
    at processImmediate (timers.js:658:5)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at Immediate.setImmediate (D:\HeliosStudio_1.0.0\nodejs\node_modules\generator-jhipster-primeng\node_modules\generator-jhipster\node_modules\yeoman-generator\lib\index.js:433:22)
    at runCallback (timers.js:705:18)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:676:5)
    at processImmediate (timers.js:658:5)
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The jhipster-primeng module has not been updated for JHipster 6, please report a bug to its authors https://github.com/sudheerj/generator-jhipster-primeng/issues

Comment: As a temporary workaround, you can edit `node_modules\generator-jhipster-primeng\generators\app\index.js:33` and replace `getJhipsterAppConfig` with `getAllJhipsterConfig` (this will be reverted any time you `npm install` or re-install the module)

Comment: @JonRuddell That worked perfectly. If you make it an answer, you'll have at least my vote. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your help, it works.